# jQuery $.get being called multiple times...why?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am building this slideshow, hereby a temp URL:

http://ferdy.dnsalias.com/apps/jungledragon/html/tag/96/homepage/slideshow/mostcomments

There are multiple ways to navigate, clicking the big image goes to the next image, clicking the arrows go to the next or previous image, and you can use your keyboard arrows as well. All of these events call a method **loadImage** (in slideshow.js).

The image loading is fine, however at the end of that routine I'm making a remote Ajax call using $.get. The purpose of this call is to count the view of that image. Here is the pseudo, snipped:

```
function loadImage(id,url) {

        // general image loading routine

        // enable loader indicator
        $("#loading").show();

        var imagePreloader = new Image();
        imagePreloader.src = url;
        loading = true;
        $(imagePreloader).imagesLoaded(function() {

            // load completed, hide the loading indicator
            $("#loading").hide();

            // set the image src, this effectively shows the image
            var img = $("#bigimage img");
            img.attr({ src: url, id: id });
            imageStartTime = new Date().getTime();

            // reset the image dimensions based upon its orientation
            var wide = imagePreloader.width >= imagePreloader.height;
            if (wide) {
                img.addClass('wide');
                img.removeClass('high');
                img.removeAttr('height');
            } else {
                img.addClass('high');
                img.removeClass('wide');
                img.removeAttr('width');
            }

            // update thumb status
            $(".photos li.active").removeClass('active');
            $("#li-" + id).addClass('active');

            // get the title and other attributes from the active thumb and set it on the big image
            var imgTitle = $("#li-" + id + " a").attr('title');
            var userID = $("#li-" + id + " a").attr('data-user_id');
            var userName = $("#li-" + id + " a").attr('data-user_name');

            $(".caption").fadeOut(400,function(){
                $(".caption h1").html('<a href="' + basepath + 'image/' + id + '">' + imgTitle + '</a>');
                $(".caption small").html('Uploaded by <a href="' + basepath + 'user/' + userID + '">' + userName + '</a>');
                $(".caption").fadeIn();
            });

            // update counter
            $(".counter").fadeOut(400,function() { $(".counter").text(parseInt($('.photos li.active .photo').attr('rel'))+1).fadeIn(); });

        // call image view recording function
        $.get(basepath + "image/" + id + "/record/human");

        // loading routine completed
        loading = false;

}
```

There is a lot of stuff in there that is not relevant. At the end you can see I am doing the $.get call. The problem is that it is triggered in very strange ways. The first time I navigate to a tumb, it is called once. The next time it is triggered twice. After that, it is triggered 2 or 3 times per navigation action, usually 3.

I figured it must be that my events return multiple elements and therefore call the loadimage routine multiple times. So I placed log statements in both the events and the loadimage routine. It turns out loadimage is called correctly, only once per click.

This means that it seems that the $.get is doing this within the context of a single call. I'm stunned.

Comment: hmm one thing i see is that for $(imagePreloader).imagesLoaded(function() {... you are missing a closing bracket?

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, a partial paste. the real code does have the bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem may be:`.imagesLoaded` is a jQuery plug in that runs through all images on the page. If you want to attach a load event to the `imagePreloader` only, use

```
$(imagePreloader).load(function() {
   ...
}
```

Otherwise, please provide the code where you call the `loadImage()` function.

**Update**:
 *when clicking on a thumb* That is the problem. `$(".photos li a").live('click',...` should only be called once on page load. Adding a `click` handler every time a thumb is clicked will not remove the previous handlers.

Another option is to change the code to `$(".photos li a").unbind('click').live('click', ...` which will remove the previously registered click handlers.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but I cannot use .load because that is not triggered in IE for cached images. Here is the code that calls loadimage when clicking on a thumb:  $(".photos li a").live('click',function(e) {
  // manually load the image that the user clicked in the thumb gallery
  $("#loading").show();
  var url = this.rel;
  var id = this.id.substring(6);
  loadImage(id,url);
  e.preventDefault();
 });

Comment: It seems you are right though, if I log something from within the imagesloaded routine I can see how it is called multiple times for one click. Now I'm stuck because switching to .load is no option either.

Comment: @scrummeister: I don't understand your answer. The reason I am using "live" here is because it also need to work on new thumbs coming from the server, as in a pagination scenario. I also don't understand what you mean by "adding" click handlers, I thought I was only registering for them. I did try your unbind suggestion, but the issue remains.

Comment: Note: for now I have moved the get call outside the imagesloaded handler, yet still inside the loadimage routine. This resolves this particular issue, yet I would still like to solve the issue in general, since a lot of stuff inside the preloading handler is now needlessly called multiple times.

Comment: @ferdy 1) `.live` will automatically picks up the new elements added to the dom and match the selector, and does not need to be called again. 2) You can use `.die()` instead of `unbind()`. Explanation: calling `.live('click'...)` doesn't **replace** the `click` event, it **adds** a `click` event. So the second time a thumb is clicked, making another `.live()` call - *which includes elements that already have a `click` event attached when the first thumb was clicked* you are **adding** a click handler, so now when one of the elements are clicked, it will call the function twice.

Comment: Yeah unbind and live combination does not work. It has to be either unbind() and bind() or die() and live().